# Push Docker images to Google Container Registry using fabric8-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, google-cloud-platform, fabric8

I'm using the [fabric8-maven-plugin](https://maven.fabric8.io) to build a Docker image on Jenkins running on Google Cloud Platform.

The plugin provides functionality to push the image to a Docker registry, but I can't make it work with [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/), because it cannot authenticate.

From my Jenkins pipeline, I can access the registry just fine using `GCloudBuildWrapper` and `gcloud docker -- push`.

For accessing Docker registries, the fabric8 Maven plugin can be used with credentials or [extended authentication](https://maven.fabric8.io/#extended-authentication), but that seems to be for AWS only at this point.

So is it possible at all to use the fabric8 Maven plugin to push Docker images to  Google Container Registry?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to my problem [in the docs for Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication). This page offers 2 approaches: Docker credential helper, which I could not get to work unfortunately, and [using an access token](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#using_an_access_token).

With the access token approach, you use 'oauth2accesstoken' as the username for GCR, and a token generated with `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` as the password. Not exactly beautiful, but it works.

Comment: Hi Otto, could you provide some code of your solution? I’m stuck on the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Building off of otto's solution:

You need to specify, in `~/.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<server>
  <id>gcr.io/<!--your-registry--></id>
  <username>oauth2accesstoken</username>
  <password><!-- gcloud oauth token goes here --></password>
</server>
```

Then when you refer to this registry by id in your `pom.xml` it'll login automatically.

You *must* use `oauth2accesstoken` as the username.